# Alternative to solution with aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select all objects for which I don't have the privilege to perform INSERT actions on. I came up with this solution which uses an aggregate function:

```
select  * from (
                SELECT table_name, type, LISTAGG(privilege, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY privilege) privlist_agg
                FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS
                group by table_name, type
                )  
where not regexp_like(privlist_agg,'INSERT')
order by type;
```

I couldn't think about how to solve this without aggregate function but I'm sure it's possible. How would that be done?

Comment: where privlist_agg not like '%INSERT%' would do the job as well, of course.

Comment: Your current query doesn't use analytic functions...?

Comment: True, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could list the objects with:

```
select table_schema, table_name, type
from all_tab_privs
group by table_schema, table_name, type
having count(case when privilege = 'INSERT' then privilege end) = 0
order by type, table_schema, table_name;
```

If you want to see the privs you *do* have, on one line, then you still need to use `listagg()`; but that's an aggregate function, not an analytic function, both as used in your original query and in how you would use it here:

```
select table_schema, table_name, type,
  listagg(privilege, '; ') within group (order by privilege) as privileges
from all_tab_privs
group by table_schema, table_name, type
having count(case when privilege = 'INSERT' then privilege end) = 0
order by type, table_schema, table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
select table_name, type
from (
    SELECT
        table_name,
        type,
        case when privilege = 'INSERT' then 1 else 0 end as is_insert
    from ALL_TAB_PRIVS
) dt
group by table_name, type
having sum(is_insert) = 0;
```